# How to create text index with default language using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fulltext-index

I can't figure out how i set default language from Python/Pymongo.

From the mongo console I can create the Index that I want like this:
`>> db.collection.createIndex({"column1": "text", "column2": "text"}, {"default_language": "none"})`

From Python/Pymongo I can create the same text index, but without the "default_language" like this: 
`collection.create_index([("column1", "text"), ("column2", "text")])`

I would like to set default_language also from the Pymongo call. How do I do that syntactically?

Comment: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's semi-documented; [the documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index) states:

> See [the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) for a full list of supported options by
>   server version.

So it's as straightforward as passing it as an additional argument:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, TEXT

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.create_index(name='index1', keys=[('column1', TEXT), ('column2', TEXT)], default_language='none')
```

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to make helpful answers as accepted, it's useful to the next person that has the same issue.